# How to add corresponding elements of two dicts in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dicts of the following type:

```
dict1 = {
   "name1": {
        "quantity" : 23,
        "totalCost": 110.0
    }, ......
}
dict2 = {
   "name1": {
        "quantity" : 45,
        "totalCost": 70.0
    },
   "name2": {
        "quantity" : 60,
        "totalCost": 120.0
    }, ......
}
```

The two dicts CAN have the same dict values or different dict values, while "quantity" and "totalCost" are fixed parameters. I want my resultant dict to be the sum of the two as follows:

```
dict1 = {
   "name1": {
        "quantity" : 68,
        "totalCost": 180.0
    },
   "name2": {
        "quantity" : 60,
        "totalCost": 120.0
    }, ......
}
```

I could use two for loops but I'm finding it very hard to debug for a larger number of nested dicts. Is there an easier method that performs this update operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "quantity" and "totalCost" are fixed keys of the inside dict, you can simply do this:

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    if k not in dict1:
        dict1[k] = v
    else:
        dict1[k]["quantity"] += v["quantity"]
        dict1[k]["totalCost"] += v["totalCost"]
```